# css styles not working in react components section but works in the main src directory

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to build a basic website using react and I am facing a small problem

So this is how my directory looks like

```
/src
  /components
    Home.js
    Home.css
  App.js
  App.css
  image.jpg
```

My App.js contains the following code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component ={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and Home.js contains the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import pict from '../image.jpg'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Pix">
        <img src={pict}/>;
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Now I want to apply style to this image but I am not able to do this using Home.css but it is working when I do the styling in App.css.
Can anyone suggest why this is happening and also how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import each file to apply the styles in the respective components.
In you case, You need to import *Home.css* inside *Home.js* to use it.

```
import React from 'react';
import pict from '../image.jpg';
import './Home.css'; 

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Pix">
        <img src={pict}/>;
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```